Htmx JavaScript interface to process arbitrary text on the client side
What is JavaScript API for processing arbitrary content on the client side in htmx.
Htmx is good about processing body data that comes back from HTTPrequest. What if you want to process data on the client side and provide that to htmx.

https://htmx.org/api/#process
